# Errors while installing Ros-jade

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i got an error while installing Ros -jade into Ubuntu 15.04.
I followed  instructions on this website([link text](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu)).
I've done up to "$sudo apt-get update"(1.4: Installation ). But after entering command "$sudo apt-get install ros-jade-desktop-full", i got an error "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

What should  I do?

```
   Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:
 git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
 git-daemon-run
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219742/errors-while-installing-ros-jade/) by [Pato](https://answers.ros.org/users/24802/pato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You appear to have a problem with the package runit which has failed to configure. It is not a ROS dependency. You need to fix that package before you will be able to install any packages such as the ROS jade packages.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0